# Dynamically add js object to model array in 1.13

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following code:

```
var msg = this.store.createRecord({text:'first title', createdAt: "2015-06-22T20:06:06+03:00" })

this.get('model.content').pushObject(msg);

msg.save();
```

We create new record. Then push in it to the model to display. It worked perfectly in 1.9 version but after upgrading it to the newest 1.13 it breaks and shows this error:

> TypeError: internalModel.getRecord is not a function

after some researches I came out to this solution

```
this.get('messages.content').unshiftObject(message.internalModel);
```

and it partially help. Now I have two problems:

- I'm not confident if using private ember data api is a good idea
- I have an annoying delay between adding record to the model and
  rendering it on the screen. More than that if I don't call
  msg.save(); the record isn't rendered. So as far as I understood it
  waits until we have response from server and only then renders it.
  But I need opposite behaviour - I need to show the record first and
  then save it(showing the saving state for the user), this way user
  thinks that everything goes extrimely fast.

Comment: what's model and what's content here?

Comment: You're using 1.13.x, where x is what for both Ember and Ember Data?

Comment: Yes, Ember 1.13.2 and Ember Data 1.13.4

Comment: having exactly the same issue with ember": "1.13.3",    "ember-data": "1.13.5",

Answer (score 8):

One possible solution without resorting to private API is to use `toArray()` ([github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3313)):

```
var array = this.get('messages').toArray()
array.addObjects(this.get('messages'))
array.addObject(msg)
this.set('messages', array)
```

Answer (score 7):

Before 1.13:

```
this.get('content').pushObjects(messages);
```

After 1.13:

```
messages.forEach(functio(message) {
  this.get('model.content').pushObject(message._internalModel);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make all return models to array then, add array to this array

```
setPeople:function(){
    this.set('people',this.get('content').toArray())
}.observes('content')
```

then, find more person models, to array

```
getMoreUsers(){
      var self = this;
            this.set('offset', this.get('offset')+1);
            self.store.findAll('person').then(function(people){
             self.get('people').pushObjects(people.toArray());
            });
```